# Laravel Migration incorrect table definition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

When trying to run the following migration:

```
    Schema::create('languages', function(Blueprint $table){

        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('lang', 10);

        $table->string('name', 50);

        $table->integer('active', 2);

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I get the following error:

```
there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

But laravel's documentation states: `$table->increments('id');  Incrementing ID to the table (primary key)`

Any idea how handle this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is

```
$table->integer('active', 2);
```

The second argument passed to integer is a Boolean indicating whether the column should be an autoincrement column or not, and a value of `2` will be treated as a Boolean `true`

**EDIT**

If you just want a ***short*** integer (like for a Boolean value), then use

```
$table->tinyinteger('active');
```

or

```
$table->boolean('active');
```

Comment: My bad, thought the parameter was supposed to be the length!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `$table->integer('active', 2)`

Here's the method signature for `integer`:

```
public function integer($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)
```

The second argument is actually a flag for auto increment. And `2` evaluates to `true`.

You can't specify the length of an integer. However you can use a `tinyInteger` instead:

```
$table->tinyInteger('active');
```